# How to download files that were changed between releases on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

So I am a novice when it comes to github and can not figure out how to download only the files that were changed between releases on GitHub preferably in a zip archive form.

Comment: You mean other than doing `git pull`?  Because that'd be the normal way to do it.

Comment: lets say current version of software is 1.9, i need to get only the files that were changed between 1.7 to 1.8 can you do that with git pull? because i have a hard time finding out how

Comment: Are the versions indicated as tags or what?  How do you get version 1.7 or 1.8 in your scenario now?

Comment: https://github.com/nginadfoundation/nginad/releases here is an example.
i need to get only the files that were changed between 1.6.7 and 1.6.8

Answer (score 0):

Many projects, including the `nginad` one you linked in a comment, use "tags" in git to denote releases.  You can see the tags for that particular project here: https://github.com/nginadfoundation/nginad/tags

The way to get the updated files is to `git clone` the entire repository just once, at which time you can select any extant tag like this:

```
git checkout tags/1.6.7
```

Now you have a working directory containing the files as they are in "release" or tag 1.6.7.  If a new release is made, you retrieve only the changes using `git pull` and then:

```
git checkout tags/1.6.8
```

Now you have the updated version.  If needed you can construct a diff of the two working directories locally on your machine and publish it in whatever way you need, but GitHub doesn't do this for you--it only publishes each entire release as a tarball.

Comment: hey, sorry, but i still don't get how i can get only the files that were changed between versions. It does not have to be an archive, can be a directory with just the files that were changed

Comment: i ran git checkout tags/1.6.8 and git pull and it gave me this error after

You are not currently on a branch, so I cannot use any
'branch.<branchname>.merge' in your configuration file.
Please specify which remote branch you want to use on the command
line and try again (e.g. 'git pull <repository> <refspec>').
See git-pull(1) for details.